# HDMI video into an iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, hdmi

I have a small idea for an app that would use video from an HDMI source on an iPad. Would someone that has experience working with external hardware/video/input signals point me in the right direction. I'll do the work obviously, I just need a little kick in the proper direction on where to start.

Basically I just want to view video from an HDMI source in a view (UIView maybe) on my iPad. It really is that simple.

Is AVFoundation all I need for this? Thanks for any links, tips, pointers, comments or ideas.

Comment: Join the MFi licensing program and get the hardware components, tools, documentation, technical support, and certification logos needed to create AirPlay audio accessories and electronic accessories that connect to iPod, iPhone, and iPad. https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

Comment: @voromax Thanks! I didn't know about this program. But do I need this for simple HDMI video in? I don't really need any airplay functionality at this point.

Comment: I know about something like this Apple Digital AV Adapter http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD098ZM/A/apple-digital-av-adapter But this is an output. Can you add more info to your question to better understand your point?

Comment: @voromax Yeah I was looking at that, but is there any reason that AV Adapter couldn't also handle video in? I don't know anything about how hardware handles that stuff.

Comment: Do you have HDMI input on your computer? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Join the MFi licensing program and get the hardware components, tools, documentation, technical support, and certification logos needed to create AirPlay audio accessories and electronic accessories that connect to iPod, iPhone, and iPad. - [MFi Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/)

[AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188) allows you to connect the standard device inputs only such as back and front camera or microphone. So I am afraid it will be on you to interprete your custom HDMI input accessory

**Updated**

The information shared under the MFi Program is Apple Confidential. Read [MFi Program Enrollment](https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#4-0)